pyinstaller creating a package more than a GB for a simple python script having import pandas, and some operations
When I run pyinstaller for such a simple script sam.py as below, the package size is worth 1.6 GB...How do we justify sharing this big file to someone ? Is it normal ?
import pandas as pd

d = pd.read_csv("~/a.csv")
cols = ['a', 'b']
d[cols].to_csv("~/new.csv", index = False)


Package size
1.6G    _internal
48M    sam

The package was generated with the spec file with the command pyinstaller sam.spec where the spec file was generated using pyinstaller sam.py and later edited to increase recursion limit to resolve related issues
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)  # Increase recursion limit

The _internal package shows the following large files:
126M    libLLVM-14.so
95M botocore
72M libmkl_core.so.2
65M libmkl_avx512.so.2
63M libmkl_intel_thread.so.2
52M libmkl_avx.so.2
49M libmkl_mc3.so.2
49M libmkl_avx2.so.2
48M libmkl_mc.so.2
42M libmkl_tbb_thread.so.2
41M libmkl_def.so.2
38M libmkl_pgi_thread.so.2
34M libarrow.so.1400
31M libpython3.12.so.1.0
31M libmkl_gnu_thread.so.2
31M libicudata.so.73
31M bokeh
31M babel
29M libmkl_sequential.so.2
24M PyQt5
23M pyarrow
23M pandas
22M libmkl_intel_lp64.so.2
18M libstdc++.so.6.0.29
18M libmkl_intel_ilp64.so.2
18M libmkl_gf_lp64.so.2
17M libomptarget.rtl.level0.so
16M libmkl_vml_avx.so.2
16M libmkl_rt.so.2
16M lib-dynload


that is not normal, what command did you run?

The package was generated with the spec file with the command pyinstaller sam.spec where the spec file was generated using pyinstaller sam.py and later edited to increase recursion limit to resolve related issues @iBeMeltin

@cryptickey , once you have .spec file, re-run pyinstaller --onefile test.py , it should create a single executable file under the 'dist' subdirectory - it'll still be a monster size, but much smaller than the 1.6g . - it worked for me, i can post my workings in an 'answer' if you need

I was also able to do that, but the executable has a higher startup time...

A 1.6 GB package for your simple script is unusual. Here's how to reduce it:
First, try using --onefile with PyInstaller. This combines everything into a single executable, which might help with the size:
pyinstaller --onefile sam.py

Next, check your .spec file and exclude unnecessary libraries like matplotlib or tkinter that might be bundled by mistake:
excludes=['matplotlib', 'scipy', 'tkinter']

Also, enable the --strip option to remove debug symbols, which can bloat the package:
pyinstaller --onefile --strip sam.py

Inspect the _internal folder to see if there are any large, unnecessary files being included. Using UPX can also compress the binary further:
pyinstaller --onefile --upx-dir=/path/to/upx sam.py

Finally, double-check your environment to ensure only essential packages are installed. Following these steps should help shrink the package size significantly.

The strip option seems to be not recommended :   -s, --strip           Apply a symbol-table strip to the executable and                         shared libs (not recommended for Windows). Does it add debug symbols or remove them ?

Also, can you specify excludes in which of Analysis class or exe or collect class need to be specified. Also, I do not understand why the pyinstaller is unable to judge the imports wisely and accomodate those into _internal_ only

The _internal package has lots of .so files ... Are they coming from my system unnecessarily ?

UPX seems to have compatibility issues with Ubuntu

pyinstaller exe generated using onefile takes a lot of time to run
